# MySQL UNION: Which method is quickest

Tags: mysql, union

Normally i go for smallest code but im currently building a payment gateway which could potentially handle millions of connections a day so every tweak in code to help performance I build in, however i have a question that can only really be answered by the mysql gurus..

with a union, is it best to filter each side of the union with where clauses, or to collate the records and then do the filtering on the union set..

which one is quickest:

1)

```
select * from (
    select * from payment_routes 
    where channel_id is null 
    and currency_id != v_currency_id
    and card_id = v_card_id 
    and enabled = 1
  union 
    select * from payment_routes 
    where channel_id = p_channel_id 
    and currency_id = v_currency_id
    and card_id = v_card_id 
    and enabled = 1
) t1
join gateways g on t1.gateway_id = g.id
where t1.currency_id = v_currency_id
;
```

2) or is this smaller code, as quick/quicker (but not slower)

```
select * from (
    select * from payment_routes 
    where channel_id is null 
    and currency_id != v_currency_id
  union 
    select * from payment_routes 
    where channel_id = p_channel_id 
    and currency_id = v_currency_id
) t1
join gateways g on t1.gateway_id = g.id
where t1.currency_id = v_currency_id
and t1.card_id = v_card_id 
and t1.enabled = 1
;
```

logically, i would say (1) is quicker as each union set is filtered so less records need to be combined.

### UPDATE

I found a better way to write this without a union

```
select r.*, g.`name` 'gateway_name' 
from payment_routes r
join gateways g on r.gateway_id = g.id
where (
    (channel_id is null and currency_id != v_sell_currency_id)
    or
    (channel_id = p_channel_id and currency_id = v_sell_currency_id)
)
and card_id = v_card_id
and currency_id = v_pay_currency_id
and enabled = 1
```

Comment: Have you tried them? To see their execution time?

Comment: well JOIN tables along with where mainly depends on the indexes for the performance and UNION will do aggregation so in a small set of data all looks good but when the data grows then its a different situation. I would suggest to use `explain your query` and see the result, this will give more insight.

Comment: there is an index on gateway_id and all id's are primary keys so also indexed.  there could potentially be 10K+ rows of payment routes which i suppose i will just have to test the response times as the data grows and make a plan, but feel option 1 will probably be quickest.  Thanks for your responses.

Comment: I would expect the two-sided union with separate and complete where clauses to vastly out-perform the melded union

Comment: `JOIN` performance not only relies on index, but size of data sets (number of records). Performance depends. You haven't provided enough details for us to determine, so experiment. MySQL is pretty good at picking best method and getting better. Sometimes it's best just to ask for what you want and let MySQL decide how. If you optimize yourself, you will need to watch as data changes because some methods don't scale well.